# Multiple blogs per user, each with a blog profile page

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to to create a site where users upon admin approval, can have multiple blogs, typically differentiated by language.

Each blog should have a profile/landing page specific to that blog.

I can simply create a taxonomy term where a given term is a given blog name and I can use the [Taxonomy Permissions module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_permissions) to restrict a given term to a given user.

The part that I'm having trouble thinking through is the admin side setup so that someone who doesn't know a lot about Drupal would be able to simply set up a new blog.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided it was easier to do this with node references and let the user choose a parent from the "add blog post" screen.